# Huffman Tree for frequencies of i'th alphabets is 2^i?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, huffman-code

I‌ Prepare for Exam on DS. I‌ read my notes. one of these problem is not well-formed. anyone could describe it for me?

> > suppose in a text, the frequencies of i'th English alphabets is `2^i` (^ means power). what is the height of Huffman tree for these characters?

I‌ need someone help me...‌

Comment: Are you looking for someone to better explain the *question*, or an attempt to answer it?  If the former, my guess is that "frequencies" is being used inappropriately, and it means that the text is made of of characters from a list, where the `i`th element of that list occurs `2*i` times.

Comment: is the original test in English or is this your translation?

Answer (score 0):

The height is `n - 1`, where `n` is the size of the alphabet(let's call it `h(n)`).

Proof:

1. Base case. `n = 2`, the height is one.
2. Step: `2 ^ n > 2 ^ 0 + ... + 2 ^ (n - 1)`. Thus, the tree for an alphabet of size `n` looks this way: a root has two children: the a leaf with the `n`-th character(the most frequent one) and a root of a tree for an alphabet of size `n - 1`. It means that its height is `h(n) = h(n - 1) + 1 = (n - 2) + 1 = n - 1`.

P.S.
I assume that the height is the number of edges in the longest path to a leaf. If we define height as a number of vertices, the answer is `n`.

Comment: I think there is a typo.

Comment: @HouraAsali Where exactly?

Comment: @kraskevich Hi, i see this question but I dont understand what do u mean by "a root has two children: the a leaf with the n-th character(the most frequent one) and a root of a tree for an alphabet of size n - 1. " please explain it more.